# Python all short-circuiting with None element

Tags: python, short-circuiting

I read everywhere that Python `all` and `any` functions support short-circuiting.
However:

```
a = None
all((a is not None, a + 1 > 2))
```

Throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-6e28870e65c8>", line 1, in <module>
    all((a is not None, a + 1 > 2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I would have expected the code not to evaluate `a + 1 > 2` since `a` is `None`.
Why is this happening? Is this because each term is evaluated before the call? Am I forced to use the `and` operator as in `a is not None and a + 1 > 2`?

Comment: Why do you even want to use `all` here and why do you make it sound like the `and` would be the inconvenient one (being "forced" to use it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tuple `(a is not None, a + 1 > 2)` needs to be created before `all()` can be called. It is during the creation of the tuple that the `TypeError` is raised. `all()` doesn't even get a chance to run.

If you want to see `all`'s short circuiting in action, pass it a generator expression. For example:

```
>>> all('foobaR'[i].islower() for i in range(7))
False

>>> all('foobar'[i].islower() for i in range(7))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

In the first run `all` stops when it hits the `'R'.islower()` case since that's `False`. In the second run it keeps going until `i == 6`, which triggers an index error.

> Am I forced to use the `and` operator as in `a is not None and a + 1 > 2`?

I wouldn't say "forced"—I'm sure there other convoluted options—but yes, that's the obvious and idiomatic way to write it.

Comment: I guess I got confused by tuple and generators.